# Variable undefined in event listener even though it is initialized in constructor

Tags: javascript, class

I have created a simple canvas and setted a 'mousedown' event listener. when I click mouse on canvas, It shows that 'val' is undefined. Can anyone please explain why?

```
class Game {
    constructor() {
        this.val = 10;

        this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

        document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);

        this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onMouseClick);
    }

    onMouseClick(event){
        console.log("C2: "+this.val);
    }
}
```

Comment: `this` in an event handler is bound to the element the event is attached to. Attach the hanler like this: `this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', e => this.onMouseClick(e));`

Comment: thanks. It worked.
Just to be clear, when I used ```this.val``` in ```onMouseClick```, ```this``` was bound to ```canvas```. That's why it couldn't find any ```val``` in ```this```.

Answer (score -1):

You could also just turn the onMouseClick function to a variable

```
class Game {
    constructor() {
        this.val = 10;

        this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

        document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);

        this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onMouseClick);
    }

    onMouseClick = (event) => {
        console.log("C2: "+this.val);
    }
}
```